# How to transform a Subject into an Observable in RxJs 5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

How can we transform a Subject into an Observable in RxJs 5 ?  This functionality is useful for example when we want to expose the Subject for subscription but don't want to yield control of calling `next()` on it, and prefer to keep the issuing of new values private.

The docs (see [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md)) mention something like this:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var obs = subject.asObservable();
```

But in RxJs 5 this currently does not work (alpha 8), we get the following error:

```
"TypeError: subject.asObservable is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJS 5 is a rewrite (currently in beta) and has lots of [renamed/removed methods](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md), among other changes. One of the removed ones is `asObservable`.

You can get the same functionality by creating an observable with the private subject's subscribe function:

```
const subj = new rx.Subject();
const exposed = new rx.Observable(fn => subj.subscribe(fn));
```

Comment: any insight on the reason why it was deleted, was it considered a bad practice or something?

Comment: I've added a link to the migration guide. Like I mentioned, it's a rewrite and I guess they wanted to get rid of things they didn't see as commonly used or necessary. They also mention wanting to be compliant with es7 observables. The page ends with a section about opening issues/PRs about missing features, so you might try that.

Comment: It wasn't removed, just overlooked. It will be in the next release.

Answer (score 13):

FYI: `Subject.prototype.asObservable()` will be in the next release `5.0.0-beta.2`.

At that point, you can just call `mySubject.asObservable()`.

Comment: This is now out and working, and TSD is updated as well.

Comment: as of rxjs 6, (or 5.5 i guess it was) we can now do this using `from` right?