# async pipe with rxjs 5 Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Does "async" pipe work with "rxjs 5" Subject? If not what will be the way?
I tried `myObservable = new Observable(fn => ngrxStore.select('myreducer').subscribe(fn));` 
as clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094705/how-to-transform-a-subject-into-an-observable-in-rxjs-5)
and used `myObservable | async` in template, but it didn't work.

To add a little more clarity, Atom IDE doesn't allow asObservable() as it finds `ngrxStore.select('myreducer')` to return an `Observable`, which doesn't seem to be the case (and I am not expecting also) when I print the object in the console which say's it is a `Subject`

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. `('myreducer')` doesn't seem to be on the correct place

Comment: edited dots after `select` and re-posted.

Comment: You should be able to do that, take a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#Observables). I'm also currently following along and having trouble with observables and Subject stuff. Hopefully this is a little useful.